# Chrome WebRTC Screen Sharing Extension requires refresh

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, getusermedia

Chrome had introduced the use of extensions for WebRTC Screen Sharing. In this, each domain has to have the extension so that people install the extension in order to share the screen using webrtc.

Here is my use case:

1. During an on-going webrtc video call, if one person needs to do screen sharing and doesn't have the extension then after installing the extension one is required to refresh the page. This interrupts the call and both people need to join the call again.
2. I want to control the user experience using javascript so that refresh is not required. But if we don't do refresh, html page doesn't recognize the recently installed extension.

I have seen many open source code regarding this but none of them has use case similar to mine. They assume the extension to be installed during the session.

However, I had seen www.uberconference.com and they have similar use case. I tried installing the screen sharing extension during a live call and it did not require the page refresh and did not interrupt the call. It did the screen sharing right after extension was installed.

I could not understand how they did it as uber is not open source. Many people say that refresh is must after installing the extension. Any help in this case will be highly appreciated.

Here  is how I install the chrome extension using in-line installation:

```
$scope.installExtension= function(){

  !!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
  && !!window.chrome
  && !!chrome.webstore
  && !!chrome.webstore.install &&
  chrome.webstore.install('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/<some-id>',
    successInstallCallback,
    failureInstallCallback
  );

};

function successInstallCallback() {
  //location.reload();
}
function failureInstallCallback(error) {
  alert(error);
}
```

Comment: Download the app and open the extension folder and have a look at the source code.

Comment: which app should I download?

Answer (score 5):

This is something we recently changed in [`getScreenMedia`](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/getScreenMedia). View the [pull request](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/getScreenMedia/pull/9/files) to see how we did it:

I wrote about the changes [on my blog](http://blog.xdumaine.com/improved-chrome-extension-ux-again/), so look there for more details, but the important bits are:

> Instead of creating a communication channel on `chrome.runtime.connect`, and messaging directly, we can use external messaging. Instead of posting a message to the window, which gets picked up by the content script and passed to the background script (and vice versa), we can use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, options, callback)` and, in the background script `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal`. This works where the other solution doesn't, because background scripts are loaded immediately upon extension installation, whereas content scripts are injected on page load.

So, basically, the extension uses a different permission:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": [
      "https://example.com/*"
  ]
}
```

And a different API:

- `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` combined with `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal`

instead of

- `window.postMessage` combined with `window.addEventListener('message')` and `chrome.runtime.connect`.

At least two different sites https://apps.mypurecloud.com and https://beta.talky.io do screen sharing with inline extension installation with no reload at all.

Answer (score 0):

This may helps today. If you are running Janus demos on the localhost - just run it over **https**.

If you will run it over http : the `getDisplayMedia` function will not be declared (e.g. in Chrome), and then Janus will ask you for plugin install.

If you had installed your own Janus-server: to use https - you must to configure ssl-certificates in Janus server configs:
`janus.transport.http.jcfg` - if you're using https in server definition
`janus.transport.websockets.jcfg` - if you're using wss (and don't forget to enable secure web-socket in it)

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at Chrome Extension Inline Installation ...
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation

I was having the same problems until I put within the html <head> tag ...

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/[your-chrome-extension-id]" >
```

Your extension manifest also needs to include the domain that this head tag is on.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.